# I am resizing an image to fit my input placeholder, but it is reverting back to its original size

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, scipy, image-resizing

I am resizing an image.

This is what I did.

1. imported image using `Image.open` ( from Image package of Python) type of image is `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` and the size is

> (587,405).

2. I resized it to `(28,28)` using `im.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)`
3. This gives size as `(28,28)` and type is `numpy.ndarray`
4. When I check the size of array it is `3136` and it doesn't fit my input of shape `(1,784)`.

Where am i going wrong?

Here are other things I tried:

1. used `scipy.misc` to resize but it outputs an array size of `3136` as above.

Comment: Could you please show the code ?

Comment: 3136 = 784 * 4 so I am guessing that you have an image that is 28 by 28 with 4 colour channels, when your model was expecting a black and white image as input. It's difficult to suggest more without a runnable example.

Comment: @myrtlecat exactly! there is something wrong with image to ndarray conversion. Though its a black and white image when i resized it, it is of (28,28) but when I convert it to array, it became (28,28,4). I am figuring out this and I will be back with an update.

Comment: If `im` is a PIL `Image`, then `im.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)` should return another `Image`, not a numpy array.  It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).